# What to expect from a postdoc interview for a field rather different from mine?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, interview

I'm currently applying for postdoctoral positions in Mathematics in a field rather different from mine (computational complexity/algebraic combinatorics). It's a broad question, which I am sure some have asked before, but what questions should I expect, given that I am likely to have different expertise from them? I'm not sure what to show... apart from enthusiasm.

I know this is a vague question, but I'll accept any educated advice from the community.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your current field?

Comment: Also, what is your reason for applying for a different field?

Comment: @JW says in the question: computational complexity and algebraic combinatorics. By different field I meant 'slightly different' (spectral theory/quantum walks). It's differnet as in it is somehow related but not quite my area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I read it as the different field being computational complexity and algebraic combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend being prepared, to the extent possible, **to give a clear explanation of your own work on demand.** What did you do, and why is it interesting? Do you remember how the proofs go? When you cite others' work, do you remember how the proofs in their work go?

Keep in mind that they might show the most interest in parts of your work that seemed peripheral to you.

If you have a friend willing to help you (someone in your graduate program, perhaps), I'd recommend asking them to look at your research statement and then ask questions (in person or over Zoom, etc.) about anything that they find interesting or don't understand. Don't try to steer the conversation; rather, insofar as you can, allow them to.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What they will want to know, even if they don't make it explicit, is how your work and interests will complement theirs. In a truly good place they will also want to know how their work can help yours.

Along with this is the question of how flexible you might be and how open to collaborative work.

If there is someone at this place that you actually want to work with you might have an opportunity to mention that.

But the questions actually asked might be along the lines of "why do you want to come here?". Also there will likely be questions about your long term goals.

Answer (score 1):

It's very much like a job interview, as in that in can vary widely depending on the situation! The important thing is that you know what you want out of this, believe in that goal and let others know this.

You did your PhD in your dedicated field so you're an expert in that. Don't try to convince other people that you know what they know. Your fellow colleagues want to see that you're passionate and that you like what you do. Prepare what you can and convince yourself how you can excel in this new field by using your background.